# MaterializeCSS Navbar button not triggering side nav

Tags: css, nav, materialize

I have the following code for a side-nav:

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
  <li><a class="subheader">Last Updated:</a></li>
  <li><a>Text Here</a></li>
  <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
  <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
  <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also have the following header code:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-1">
                <a class="brand-logo center" href="#">Website Name</a>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse" href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a></li>
  </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

So why is the menu item not coming up in my nav bar and why is it not triggering the side nav?

Also, if i remove the `button-collapse` class, I am able to see the menu but clicking on it does not trigger `side-nav`

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/cr6ox4rd/) is my jsFiddle

Edit: My problem is not the icon, it's the fact that clicking on the menu icon/text does not activate the side navigation menu.

*How do I make the side-nav work on mobile AND DESKTOP*

Comment: That fiddle works fine for me on mobile, the menu button is on the right and just says menu instead of a hamburger but it's functional

Comment: @darryn.ten: Hmm youre right, it works on mobile but not desktop. How do I make it work on desktop?

Comment: I think you are not including the CSS stylesheet for Material icons, thats why it is showing the text instead of the hamburger. When I add this line `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">` to your fiddle, everything looks good to me.

Comment: @ShekharChikara: My problem is that when I click the text/hamburger, it does not activate the side-nav menu on Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `button-collapse` was setting `display:none` in CSS due to following for desktop:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px)
nav a.button-collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

Not sure the reason of it.

However you can use other class than `button-collapse` and it will work.

HTML:

```
<header>
            <div class="navbar-fixed">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-1">
                        <a class="brand-logo center" href="#">Website Name</a>
          <ul class="right">
            <li><a data-activates="slide-out" class="my-btn" href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a></li>
          </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>   
</header>
```

JS:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.my-btn').sideNav({
      edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
      draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
    }
    );

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6hfrw33n/

Answer (score 1):

> *If you want the menu to be accessible on all screensizes you just have*
>   *to add a simple helper class **show-on-large** to the  **.sidenav-trigger**.*

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-1">
                <a class="brand-logo center" href="#">Website Name</a>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large" href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a></li>
  </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

as shown here: https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html

Answer (score -2):

- Add this line in you js file **$('.button-collapse').sideNav();**